# undefined index error in php- android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I m getting this undefined index error on my localhost browser and invalid ip address on my app while running this function .

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 10
>   Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 11
>   Notice: Undefined index: mobno in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 12
>   Notice: Undefined index: dob in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 13
>   Notice: Undefined index: tob in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 15
>   Notice: Undefined index: pob in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 16
>   Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\prateek\insert.php on line 17
>   {"code":0}

```
<?php   $host='127.0.0.1';
$uname='root';  $pwd='Hunch@123';   $db="astro";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection
   failed");    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
   $queryresult = array();  $name=$_REQUEST['name'];    $gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
   $mobno=$_REQUEST['mobno'];   $dob=$_REQUEST['dob'];  $tob=$_REQUEST['tob'];  $msg=$_REQUEST['msg'];
$pob=$_REQUEST['pob'];  $email=$_REQUEST['email'];  $flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("insert into
   kundali(gender,name,email,d_o_b,t_o_b,p_o_b,mobil_no,message)
   values('$gender','$name','$email','$dob','$tob','$pob','$mobno','$msg')
   ",$con))     {       $flag['code']=1;        echo"hi";   }

print(json_encode($flag));  mysql_close($con); ?>
```

1. ```
   public void insert()
      {
          ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender",gender));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobno",mobno));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob",dob));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tob",tob));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pob",pob));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg",msg));
          try
          {
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/prateek/insert.php");
              httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              is = entity.getContent();
              Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

          try
          {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                      (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
              {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              result = sb.toString();
              Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
          }## Heading ##
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
          }

          try
          {
              JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
              code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

              if(code==1)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              else
              {
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
          }
      }
   ```

Comment: have you mixed php and android code? The way you have shown it in your question makes me think so

Comment: Can you put the complete error? and can you make sure if you are able to get response from PHP file accessed via localhost

Comment: i have posted an answer, put if you post your PHP code that will help more

Answer (score 0):

**1- Invalid IP address solve:**

change the URL in this line

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/prateek/insert.php");
```

to:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://IP_OF_SERVER/prateek/insert.php");
```

**2- Notice: Undefined index... Error:**
you need to send the parameters (name, gender, ...) the same way you read them in your PHP code,

ex, if in your PHP code you read them as `$_POST['name']`, then you need to send them as POST, and if `$_GET['name']` then send them as GET